# Interested In Feedback About My Timeout Class

Tags: c#, class, timer, timeout

Many areas in a project I'm working on have a simple timeout check which basically runs code through a try loop until it succeeds or 10 seconds elapses.

```
class Timeout {
    private readonly DateTime timeoutDate;
    public bool FlagSuccess;

    public Timeout() {
        timeoutDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(10);
        flagSuccess = false;
    }

    public bool continueRunning() {
        if (!flagSuccess && DateTime.UtcNow < timeoutDate) return true;
        else return false;
    }
}
```

Here is an example of the class in use:

```
Timeout t = new Timeout();
while (t.continueRunning()) {
    try {
        //PUT CODE HERE
        t.flagSuccess = true;
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}
```

Before I implement this, is there a better and more standard way to do this?  What I have above is based on my blind intuition.

Comment: If your `//PUT CODE HERE`-Code is a time consuming function, your check in the while-statement will not(or at least all the time it needs) been evaluated and your timer is fairly senseless.

Comment: It is okay.  At least pass the timeout value to the constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use .NETs `Timer` class(es):

```
using System.Timers;

public static void Main() {
    Timer t = new Timer();
    t.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(ActionWhenFinished);
    t.Interval = 10000;
    t.Start();
}

public static void ActionWhenFinished()
{
    // cancel any action
}
```

Your `Timeout` class will block the current thread it is running in, which isn't the case with `System.Timer`.

Comment: The comment is wrong.  It should read // Insert magic here.  The method runs on a threadpool thread, not the thread that is executing the OP's code.

Comment: ActionWhenFinished() gets called after 10sec and runs in a threadpool thread, as the Timer msdn states. Why should I not cancel my action from another thread? Feel free to correct me if Im wrong. I thought we may run into trouble if the long running action and the timer would be in the same thread because FlagSucces may be set AFTER the maximal timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Looks kind of like a busy loop to me, but here's how you'd do it with a StopWatch.

```
    System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch timer = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
    timer.Start();
    bool complete;
    while( timer.ElapsedMilliseconds < 10000 && !complete)
    {
        //Do stuff
       // and someday... complete = true;
    }
```

You could wrap that up into a simple class as well if you like.

```
class AgingWait
{
 System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch _watch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
 int maxMilliseconds;
 bool forceExpire;
 public bool Expired
 {
     get { return forceExpire || maxMilliseconds < _watch.ElapsedMilliseconds; }
 }
 public AgingWait(int milli)
 {
     _watch.Start();
     maxMilliseconds = milli;
 }

 public void Expire()
 {
     forceExpire = true;
 }
}
```

to use

```
    AgingWait waiter = new AgingWait(1000);
    while (!waiter.Expired)
    {
        if (condition)
            waiter.Expire();

    }
```

Comment: I am under the assumption you intend to have the thread blocked.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest changing your loop to a do-while loop, so that you're guaranteed to run the loop at least once even if your thread gets momentarily waylaid between setting up the timeout and starting the loop.  Also, I'd suggest that it may be helpful to have the Timeout class include a RemainingMilliseconds property, and maybe RemainingMillisecondsUpTo(Integer N) function, which could be passed to various block-or-timeout routines.